# Увеличивается память базы Realm

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

В приложении при каждом запуске я гружу расписание занятий сервера и кладу его в бд Realm. Но при каждом перезапуске приложения память увеличивается на 100 Кб (примерно). Дубликаты из БД стираю при каждой загрузке данных в БД. Продебажил, и действительно копий никаких нету.  В наследуемом классе от `Application` инициализирую Realm. В `Activity.onDestroy()` применяю `realm.close()`. В чем может быть загвоздка? На что обратить внимание?

Comment: Если делать запросы в базу из разных потоков, то она может "распухать". Чтобы уменьшить размер базы, можно вызвать [`compactRealm`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#compactRealm-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-)

Answer (score 0):

Из [документации](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#large-realm-file-size):

Realm оперирует сразу несколькими версиями базы. Предположим, вы читаете данные из Realm и блокируете поток на длительное время, а в другом потоке производите операцию по вставке данных.

В таком случае, база в первом потоке не будет обновляться, и Realm будет вынужден хранить промежуточные версии базы, которые, возможно, уже не актуальны. В  результате этого, размер базы постоянно растёт.

Выделенное дополнительное место при дальнейших операциях записи будет переиспользовано, либо может быть сжато с помощью вызова [`compactRealm`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#compactRealm-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-).

Comment: Запросы выполняются в основном потоке. Уже точно некуда копать?